# Attempt to read property "sliders" on null

Tags: laravel

I get this error when I do a migration with terminal on my cpanel mysql database:

> Attempt to read property "sliders" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website_slider.blade.php)

```
@if($company->sliders == 'on')

<!--Slider Section Start-->

<div id="rs-home-slider" class="rs-home-slider home1-slider">

    <div class="slider-carousel owl-carousel">


        @forelse($sliders as $row)

            <div class="single-slider">

                <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/sliders/' . $row->file) }}" alt="">

                <div class="content-inner2">

                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="slider-text text-center">

                            <h3 class="sl-subtitle wow fadeInDown fix__heading">{{ $row->getTranslation('text_1' , LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()) }}</h3>

                            <h1 class="sl-title wow fadeInDown fix__heading"><span class="fix__heading">{{ $row->getTranslation('text_2' , LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()) }} </span>{{ $row->getTranslation('text_3' , LaravelLocalization::getC

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        @empty


            <div class="single-slider">

                <img src="{{ asset('website/images/slider/default_slider.jpg') }}" alt="">

                <div class="content-inner2">

                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="slider-text text-center">

                            <h3 class="sl-subtitle wow fadeInDown fix__heading">{{ __('website.title1') }}</h3>

                            <h1 class="sl-title wow fadeInDown fix__heading"><span>{{ __('website.title2') }} </span>{{ __('website.title3') }}</h1>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

this is a screen shot for the problem.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7BAe.png)

slider controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin\Slider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class SliderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $sliders = Slider::all();
        return view('admin.slider.index' , compact('sliders'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.slider.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('file')) {
            // Get Filename With The Extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get Just Filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get Just Extension
            $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // File To Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/images/sliders/' , $fileNameToStore);
        }else {
            $fileNameToStore = '';
        }

        Slider::create([
            'file' => $fileNameToStore,
            'text_1' => ['ar' => $request->text_1_ar,'en' => $request->text_1_en],
            'text_2' => ['ar' => $request->text_2_ar,'en' => $request->text_2_en],
            'text_3' => ['ar' => $request->text_3_ar,'en' => $request->text_3_en],
            'created_by' => auth()->user()->id,
            'status' => $request->status ? 'active' : 'inactive',
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('admin.sliders.index')->with('success' , __('main.data has been added'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $slider = Slider::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.slider.edit' , compact('slider'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $slider = Slider::findOrFail($id);
        $oldFile = $slider->file;

        if($request->hasFile('file')) {
            // Get Filename With The Extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get Just Filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get Just Extension
            $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // File To Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/images/sliders/' , $fileNameToStore);
        }

        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $slider->file = $fileNameToStore;
            if($oldFile != ''){
                Storage::delete('public/images/sliders/' . $oldFile);
            }
        }

        $slider->text_1 = ['ar' => $request->text_1_ar,'en' => $request->text_1_en];
        $slider->text_2 = ['ar' => $request->text_2_ar,'en' => $request->text_2_en];
        $slider->text_3 = ['ar' => $request->text_3_ar,'en' => $request->text_3_en];
        $slider->status = $request->status ? 'active' : 'inactive';

        $slider->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.sliders.index')->with('success' , __('main.data has been updated'));
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $slider = Slider::findOrFail($id);
        if($slider){
            Storage::delete('public/images/sliders/' . $slider->file);
            $slider->delete();
        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.sliders.index')->with('success' , __('main.deleted done'));
    }

}
```

I tried to resolve the problem but I didn't find any answer for my question.
can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Your variable `$company` is null. What does your controller code look like?

Comment: That's what I was about to say. Adding another check should fix it but now you should look for the reason why `$company` is null
```@if(isset($company) && $company->sliders == 'on')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that you're trying to access the "sliders" property of an object, but the object itself is null. This typically happens when you're trying to access a property of an object that hasn't been initialized or doesn't exist.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that the "$company" variable is properly initialized and contains the expected data before trying to access its "sliders" property. You should check if "$company" is not null before accessing its properties. Here's how you can do it:

```
@if($company && $company->sliders == 'on')
    // Your code here
@endif
```

This conditional check ensures that "$company" is not null before attempting to access its "sliders" property.

Comment: now I have this error
Call to a member function getTranslation() on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\app.blade.php)

Comment: replace @forelse part with this: 

@forelse($sliders ?? [] as $row)